# A spell that let's you travel to another setting. Which level would it be?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew, campaign-settings

My last campaign took place in the Forgotten Realms. The characters lived in a kingdom, which was threatened to be annihilated by some strange outside force. In the course of the story, the characters found more and more information about what was going on, including the fact that the knowledge they require to save their homeland was long lost. At least it was long lost in the Forgotten Realms. Fortunately, the party found a mysterious gateway that brought them to Golarion. The characters had to overcome some obstacles in this unfamiliar place, including the language barrier, that there was no Weave, clerics missing their gods ... things like that. The players liked it, so after getting the stuff they needed in Golarion, I let them visit another place outside the Forgotten Realms setting before they got home.

That campaign is over now  and the crisis was averted. At least for the time being. My current campaign takes place 20 years after the last one. Different player characters, but with some well-known NPCs from the last campaign as supporting cast. This time, the whole universe hangs in the balance! The usual plot, standard D&D fare. Because the players liked the setting-hopping during the last campaign, I plan to include stuff like that in my plot. Last time, I just established that there was a portal to a faraway place and that they had to jump through some hoops to activate it. So the powerful magic that got them to Golarion was already there. They just had to jump-start it.

There are some interesting places they could visit, like Greyhawk, Athas, Eberron, maybe Ravnica. There are no limits. Well … there are some limits. Not only do I have to get them from one setting to the next, I would also like to introduce antagonists who can follow them. That’s why I have to know how powerful magic has to be, in order to transport someone to another setting. There is the *planeshift* spell, but it only lets you (as the name implies) travel to another plane. So I’m looking for a spell that can do more, some kind of *realmshift* spell. So my main question is, which level would a spell like that be.

Would it be on the same power level as an 8th level spell, so it could be (theoretically) replicated with a *wish*, without risking to never cast it again? Would a spell like that be 9th level? Can I *wish* for it, and potentially lose the power to cast *wish* again? Or is magic like that beyond 9th level? Maybe Divine Intervention? I’m not sure.

I know that there are some kind of fantasy spaceships available, but I have no experience with Spelljammer. So I don’t know how that works and how powerful a spaceship’s magic(?) engine has to be in order to overcome the boundaries of a setting.

Comment: @Stackstuck You can and should make such arguments only in answers. Frame-challenge can be a valid way to craft an answer. But comments are not for such things: they are only for improving the question.

Comment: Why is the "power" or level of the spell a limit to anything? A DM can freely determine such things and decide how easy or hard it is to move between settings (though I wouldn't ordinarily expect it to be so easy that just anyone can do it of course!).

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I feel like frame-challenge is valid both in answers (if you have a suggestion of resolution for your challenge) *or* as commentary (if you only have a challenge that might result in a more answerable question, but don't have the *answer to that question*). I'm going to make a new Meta question...

Comment: @NautArch in previous d&d versions of the game the spelljammer setting specifically unified all of the settings so travel between them was possible. D&D 5e has included spelljammer ships in canon (see my answer). The OP has specifically mentioned spelljammer ships in their question, meaning they are open to this in the answer.

Comment: Link to the related meta question: [Is a “Frame Challenge” really only valid as an answer or can it be commentary as well?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8926/is-a-frame-challenge-really-only-valid-as-an-answer-or-can-it-be-commentary-as)

Comment: I honestly don't see why this is marked as "too broad". I would understand if it were "primarily opinion-based", but "too broad"? I myself think this question should be answerable in one or two paragraphs. Or at least in fewer words than other answers around here. I simply want to know, if a spell that let's you travel to another realm would be something a player character could achieve, for example with a 9th level spell or a wish, or if Divine Intervention would be possible/enough. Plus, I would appreciate some suggestions on making my question less broad, instead of just closing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5e has very few rules for campaigns involving multiple realms.  The best reference you're going to get, then, is previous editions.  In previous editions, these sorts of things were handled either as spelljammer spheres (which had their own setting in between and required that you have special "spelljammer" ships to make the trek) or "alternate prime material planes".

So, for the closest you're going to get to RAW (not very close), you should either hand your players a spelljammer and run it that way, or embrace the idea of alternate prime material planes and just let plane shift work.

There aren't any 5e rules for spelljammer either, so you'll have to make up your own.  Fortunately, they're pretty relaxed about some things.  Fundamentally, in order to make a spelljammer work, you need two things - a ship, and a Helm.  The ship can be almost anything, but is generally the size of a standard sailing vessel.  The helm is a powerful magical item that you bolt to the vessel in order to make it a spelljammer, and it runs off of magic, in various forms (generally by consuming spell slots or magical items, though a number of other, weirder options also exist).  If you want to go for that, I'd suggest you look around the web for spelljammer conversions for 5e, and see what you can pick up there.  Alternately, if your campaign is going to take a whiel to get there, you might try waiting patiently.  We've certainly gotten hints that a spelljammer supplement is coming out at some point.

Answer (score 6):

## The *Well of Many Worlds* magic item could provide this mechanic for you

The *Well of Many Worlds* states:

> You can use an action to unfold and place the **well of many worlds** on a solid surface, whereupon it creates a two-way portal to another world or plane of existence.

While a "plane of existence" is well defined in game terms, "another world" is not and could easily be interpreted by the DM to be another campaign setting.

It is a *legendary* magic item, and thus equivalent to the very highest level of spellcasting (given that the planeshift spell does something similar it is suggestive of being a requirement to use 7th/8th level spells at the very least).

## A published adventure contains some details of a spelljammer ship

> In the Dungeon of the Mad Mage Halaster has a trapped spelljammer ship in Undermountain and stolen it's helm. The adventure explicitly states it is possible for the characters to recover the helm and take possession of the ship and use it thereafter (with some conditions on getting it **out** of Undermountain). The adventure also provides a deck map of the ship in question!

Comment: It may be worth expanding on what a spelljammer ship actually is, for those who aren't familiar

Comment: @DavidCoffron will do when I get a chance